# Ubuntu Upgrade Package Problem | libpq5_10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb Not Found

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

Trying to upgrade the packages using command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But it says **url not found**. I also tried to check the url and it's 404 not found.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-alienware17-r5:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpq5
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 108 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libpq5 amd64 10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-10/libpq5_10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: *`maybe run apt-get update`* Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. I have tried.

Comment: What did you get? What is the output of `apt-cache policy libpq5`? The version in Ubuntu pool is 10.8-0ubuntu0.18.04.1.